# How to substitute single character with a string

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need some alternative on translate function.

In the following example all the spaces will be replaced by the `!` character:

```
translate('text ','&#32;', '!')
```

which would output: `text!!` correct?

What I want is to substitute the space (`&#32;`) character with a string instead of another character.

In order to explain I will post the next line which is illegal:

```
translate('text ','&#32;', '&amp#160;')
```

This is the desired output:

```
text&#160;&#160;
```

Comment: Well XSLT/XPath 2.0 have a `replace` function.  On the other hand while you can do `replace('text  ', ' ', '&#160;')` this will replace a space with a non-breaking space, if you want to ensure in the final serialization you get a numeric character reference then you need to use a character map defining that.

Comment: @MartinHonnen
Replace function did the job. You helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @RadoslawKrasimirow Replacing a space with a non-breaking space is a one-to-one character substitution and **can** be performed by the `translate()` function.

Comment: The problem is that I want space characters to be rendered to a literal string `&#160;` not to a blank space in the editor pane. It is difficult to express myself, because 
first - English is not my native language second - I am not familiar with the terminology. It is quite likely to misunderstand me. Happily I got the answer that helped me.